# Jquery Autocomplete results link not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the jquery autocomplete.i am getting the search results from database.
basically when i start typing in search box i am getting some suggestions.I have given the link for the results using `<a href="results.html>`. but when i click on those suggestions i am not getting to `results.html`

I need to redirect to results.html page onclick on some suggestions how can i do that?

Code:Jquery

```
$().ready(function() {
$("#search").autocomplete("php/getvalues.php", {
    width: 383,
    matchContains: true,
    //mustMatch: false,
    //minChars: 0,
    //multiple: true,
    //highlight: true,
    //multipleSeparator: ",",
    selectFirst: false
});
```

});

getvalue.php

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = "select file_name,img_url,captions from completer";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $fname = $rs['file_name'];
    $iurl = $rs ['img_url'];
    $caption = $rs ['captions'];
    echo '<a href="results.html" class="searchres" style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;"><img src='.$iurl.' class="icons" /><div class="results" style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;">'."$fname".'</div><span style="color:#696969;text-decoration:none;" class="author">'.$caption.'</span></a>'."\n";
}
?>
```

html:

```
<form method="post" name="myform" class="ourform">
<input type="search" id="search" name="search" placeholder="Type or speak here to search">
<input type="image" alt="submit" src="images/search.jpg" class="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Consider posting the code in your answer, when the link expires nobody will understand what we are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put an action in your form element like so:

```
<form method="post" name="myform" class="ourform" action="/results.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working

i just used simple javascript to do it

```
onclick="window.location.assign(this.id)"
```

is working fine now. :)